# Proving Row-Equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have a problem that asks:

If A, B, and C are m x n matrices, show that:

A ~ A

If A ~ B then B ~ A

If A ~ B and B ~ C then A ~ C

Now I know the definition of row equivalence is that two matrices are row equivalent if one can be converted into the other using elementary row operations. My question is how do I show this as a proof?

Let's take the easy first one as an example. If I were to say:

Proof:

By the definition of row equivalence, for two matrices to be equivalent, one must be able to be converted into the other using elementary row operations. Therefore it suffices to show row equivalence through elementary row operations.

Using the elementary operation: $R_i -> kR_i$

In particular: A -> 1A = A

Since A can reach itself through elementary operations, A ~ A.

END OF PROOF

Would something like this work? If not what would a formal proof showing row equivalence look like?

Comment: Yes, your proof (*for reflexivity*) is fine, and perhaps may be a bit more intuitive to the untrained eye, but I will point out that the *empty sequence* of row operations is still technically a sequence of row operations, so it could have been done in zero steps rather than in one step.  You still have symmetry and transitivity left to prove.  A hint there, consider trying to show that an elementary row operation can be reversed, and further that two sequences of operations can be combined one after another.

Comment: Every elementary row operation on a matrix can be represented as left multiplication by an [elementary matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix), so if you want a rigorous proof, you can show the equivalences by representing one of the matrices as a product of elementary matrices with right multiplication with the latter matrix.

Comment: @JMoravitz For symmetry, would it work to just show the reverse of each operation, give a particular example, and comment how the reverse sequence of operations are valid and thus means that the statement holds? For transitivity, can I just say that since A ~ B and B ~ C holds then there exists a sequence that goes from A to B and from B to C so if you were to use the sequence from A to B starting at A and adding on the sequence from B to C will yield a sequence of operation that goes from A to C and thus that statement holds?

Comment: "*...give a particular example...*"  Particular examples may be helpful to you or the reader, but are by no means necessary.  Otherwise, yes that is exactly what needs to be done.  Alternatively, using Prasun's suggestion, recognize that the "reverse" of an elementary row operation is just the inverse of the corresponding elementary matrix.  That is to say, $E_kE_{k-1}\cdots E_2E_1 A = B\iff A=E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}\cdots E_{k-1}^{-1}E_k^{-1}B$

Comment: Ahh I see. Thank you for the clarification. One last question. Should I just leave this question up or delete it seeing how there were no official answers?

Comment: The best way to handle situations like this is to write up an answer yourself and accepting it as the best answer, thus the post doesn't go unanswered and future users having the same problem can look up this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to JMoravitz, the approach to A ~ A is correct.

For the other two it suffices to show that:

Symmetry: show the reverse of each operation, and comment how the reverse sequence of operations are valid and thus means that the statement holds.

Transitivity: Since A ~ B and B ~ C holds then there exists a sequence that goes from A to B and from B to C so if you were to use the sequence from A to B starting at A and adding on the sequence from B to C will yield a sequence of operation that goes from A to C and thus that statement holds.

For a more rigorous proof one may want to take Prasun Biswas' approach explained in the comments.